# Shell script to recursively print full directory tree using ls

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

Assignment: I have to create a shell script using diff and sort, and a pipeline using ls -l, grep '^d', and awk '{print $9}' to print a full directory tree.

I wrote a C program to display what I am looking for. Here is the output:

```
ryan@chrx:~/Documents/OS-Projects/Project5_DirectoryTree$ ./a.out 
TestRoot/
[Folder1]
  [FolderC]
  [FolderB]
  [FolderA]
[Folder2]
  [FolderD]
  [FolderF]
  [FolderE]
[Folder3]
  [FolderI]
  [FolderG]
  [FolderH]
```

I wrote this so far:

```
ls -R -l $1 | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'
```

to print the directory tree but now I need a way to sort it by folder depth and possibly indent but not required. Any suggestions? I can't use find or tree commands.

EDIT: The original assignment & restrictions were mistaken and changed at a later date. The current answers are good solutions if you disregard the restrictions so please leave them for any people with similar issues. As for the the new assignment in case anybody was wondering. I was to recursively print all sub directories, sort them, then compare them with my program to make sure they have similar results. Here was my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Program:
./a.out $1 | sort
echo Shell Script:
ls -R -l $1 | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}' | sort

diff <(./a.out $1 | sort) <(ls -R -l $1 | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}' | sort)
DIFF=$?

if [[ $DIFF -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "The outputs are similar!"
fi
```

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do (e.g. `grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'` = `awk '/^d/{print $9}'`), the tool to recursively find directories is `find -type d`, not `ls -R`, and what does this have to do with diff or sort?

Comment: I understand that. The restrictions, diff, & sort are just part of the given assignment. I'd would write the script much differently if I could.

Comment: But what would you diff, for example? You could throw in a `diff /etc/password /dev/null > /dev/null` somewhere in the script just to use `diff` and I doubt if you'd get any points for that but I just cant imagine what you'd use diff for in this problem.

Comment: I know right. My professors description of this makes little sense even to me. That's why I'm asking here. I'm thinking of just going against the paper on this one though. At least I know i'm not crazy.

Comment: Does that script need to be a one liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need neither `ls` nor `grep` nor `awk` for getting the tree. The Simple recursive `bash` function will be enouh, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
walk() {
        local indent="${2:-0}"
        printf "%*s%s\n" $indent '' "$1"
        for entry in "$1"/*; do
                [[ -d "$entry" ]] && walk "$entry" $((indent+4))
        done
}
walk "$1"
```

If you run it as `bash script.sh /etc` it will print the dir-tree like:

```
/etc
    /etc/apache2
        /etc/apache2/extra
        /etc/apache2/original
            /etc/apache2/original/extra
        /etc/apache2/other
        /etc/apache2/users
    /etc/asl
    /etc/cups
        /etc/cups/certs
        /etc/cups/interfaces
        /etc/cups/ppd
    /etc/defaults
    /etc/emond.d
        /etc/emond.d/rules
    /etc/mach_init.d
    /etc/mach_init_per_login_session.d
    /etc/mach_init_per_user.d
    /etc/manpaths.d
    /etc/newsyslog.d
    /etc/openldap
        /etc/openldap/schema
    /etc/pam.d
    /etc/paths.d
    /etc/periodic
        /etc/periodic/daily
        /etc/periodic/monthly
        /etc/periodic/weekly
    /etc/pf.anchors
    /etc/postfix
        /etc/postfix/postfix-files.d
    /etc/ppp
    /etc/racoon
    /etc/security
    /etc/snmp
    /etc/ssh
    /etc/ssl
        /etc/ssl/certs
    /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Your solution is pretty cool, but the original post set out the requirements of _I have to create a shell script using diff and sort, and a pipeline using ls -l, grep '^d', and awk '{print $9}' to print a full directory tree._

Comment: @RogerSinasohn , It is a good solution regarding the original question if you disregard restrictions. I added an edit explaining that the assignment was described incorrectly and I added my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @jm666's idea of running it on /etc:

```
$ find /etc -type d -print | awk -F'/' '{printf "%*s[%s]\n", 4*(NF-2), "", $0}'
[/etc]
    [/etc/alternatives]
    [/etc/bash_completion.d]
    [/etc/defaults]
        [/etc/defaults/etc]
            [/etc/defaults/etc/pki]
                [/etc/defaults/etc/pki/ca-trust]
                [/etc/defaults/etc/pki/nssdb]
            [/etc/defaults/etc/profile.d]
            [/etc/defaults/etc/skel]
    [/etc/fonts]
        [/etc/fonts/conf.d]
    [/etc/fstab.d]
    [/etc/ImageMagick]
    [/etc/ImageMagick-6]
    [/etc/pango]
    [/etc/pkcs11]
    [/etc/pki]
        [/etc/pki/ca-trust]
            [/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted]
                [/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java]
                [/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl]
                [/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem]
            [/etc/pki/ca-trust/source]
                [/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors]
                [/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/blacklist]
        [/etc/pki/nssdb]
        [/etc/pki/tls]
    [/etc/postinstall]
    [/etc/preremove]
    [/etc/profile.d]
    [/etc/sasl2]
    [/etc/setup]
    [/etc/skel]
    [/etc/ssl]
    [/etc/texmf]
        [/etc/texmf/tlmgr]
        [/etc/texmf/web2c]
    [/etc/xml]
```

Sorry, I couldn't find a sensible way to use the other tools you mentioned so it may not help you but maybe it'll help others with the same question but without the requirement to use specific tools.

Comment: Agreed. Still useful! Thank you